# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (128) must match the size of tensor b (16) at non-singleton dimension 0

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model. I am facing issue while doing the training iteration for my model. The code is as below:
I have used nn.CrossEntropyLoss() function to track the losses

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

```
epochs = 10

epoch_log = []
loss_log = []
accuracy_log = []

for epoch in range(epochs):
  print(f'starting epoch : {epoch+1}...')

  running_loss = 0.0

  for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    inputs, labels = data

    # move our data to GPU
    inputs = inputs.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)

    #set the gradients to zero
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Forward -> backprop + optimize
    outputs = net(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    running_loss += loss.item()
    if i % 50 == 49:
      correct = 0
      total = 0

      with torch.no_grad():

        for data in testloader:
          images, labels = data

          images = images.to(device)
          labels = labels.to(device)

          outputs = net(inputs)

          _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, dim = 1)

          total += labels.size(0)
          correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

      accuracy = 100 * correct / total
      epoch_num = epoch + 1
      actual_loss = running_loss / 50
      print(f"Epoch : {epoch_num}, mini-batches completed : {(i+1)}, Loss : {actual_loss:.3f}, Test Accuracy : {accuracy:.3f}%")
      running_loss = 0.0
   
   # store training stats after each epoch
epoch_log.append(epoch_nmum)
loss_log.append(actual_loss)
accuracy_log.append(accuracy)

print("Training Completed")
```

Now when I run this code I am facing this error even though I have done everything right.

```
starting epoch : 1...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b3f8854281bf> in <module>
     44 
     45           total += labels.size(0)
---> 46           correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
     47 
     48       accuracy = 100 * correct / total

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (128) must match the size of tensor b (16) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

Please help me solve this problem so that it will help me and many others in the future.

Comment: Try `outputs = net(images)` instead of `outputs = net(inputs)`. I guess you wanted to use `images` there, because otherwise you don't use it anywhere and you defined the same `output` before.

Answer (score 0):

As [Gandhi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16977407/gandhi) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756145/runtimeerror-the-size-of-tensor-a-128-must-match-the-size-of-tensor-b-16-at#comment131936241_74756145), `outputs = net(inputs)` should be `outputs = net(images)`.